# Adding a Control to Beginning of a FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: vb.net, winforms, flowlayoutpanel

I have a program that grabs product data and adds a custom control for each record to a FlowLayoutPanel.

I would like to add a control to the beginning of the FlowLayoutPanel, as opposed to the end, to appear as the first item.

Does anyone have an idea how this is done? I would like to avoid having to repopulate it every time I add an item to the beginning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [SetChildIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the FlowLayoutPanel's Control collection:

```
Dim newButton As New Button With {.Text = flp.Controls.Count.ToString}
flp.SuspendLayout()
flp.Controls.Add(newButton)
flp.Controls.SetChildIndex(newButton, 0)
flp.ResumeLayout()
```

Comment: SuspendLayout please.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't even know to look for that. Worked perfect!